# How to calculate a polygonal line size

Tags: haskell

i have a doubt in haskell, as i need to calculate the size of a polygonal size, basically is the size of a line given certain points of the lines.

i came to this:

```
type Points = (Float, Float) -- (x,y)
type Rectangle = (Points,Float,Float) -- (Top left corner., width,height)
type Triangulo = (Points,Points,Points)
type Poligonal = [Points]

distance :: Points -> Points -> Float
distance (a,b) (c,d) = sqrt (((c-a)^2) + ((b-d)^2))

poli :: Poligonal -> Float
poli [] = 0
poli ((a,b):(c,d):ys)= distance (a,b) (c,d) + poli ys
```

What this does is, it calculates all the size of the lines defined by dots/points but never calculates the final position:

```
poli [(0.0,0.0),(1.1,1.0),(20.0,12.0)]
1.4866068

poli [(0.0,0.0),(1.1,1.0),(20.0,12.0),(2.0,3.0)]
21.611217

...
```

It needs 2 points to give the line size

1---------2----------3

it calculates 1-2, but not 2-3

I am learning haskell, so i hope you can point me in the right direction.

Cheers to all

Answer (score 1):

Another way to define `poli` would be:

```
poli :: Poligonal -> Float
poli [] = 0
poli (x:xs) = sum $ zipWith distance (x:xs) xs
```

We use [`zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3azipWith) to pair every element in the list (except the last) with its next element, and return a list of the distances. Then we sum the list.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick.

```
poli :: Poligonal -> Float
poli [] = 0
poli ((a,b):[]) = 0
poli ((a,b):(c,d):ys)= distance (a,b) (c,d) + poli ((c,d):ys)
```

Comment: Since `poli` doesn't actually use the individual coordinates of each point, you could write something like `poli (x:y:ys) = distance x y + poli (y:ys)` instead, it's a bit clearer.

Comment: Also, your function is not tail recursive (see here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tail_recursion) and that could cause problems for really long lists of points. You could add a strict accumulating parameter to make it tail recursive: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Accumulating_parameter